# How to add more actions in the Health cloud Patient List view

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

[image]

In the Picture near the 3, we have Action and Create Task in the dropdown.
How can I add more Actions in the drop down like "Create Note", "Log Call"

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce lightning mode, Go to **Setup**->**Object Manager**-> **Patient** object.

Click on **Buttons, Links and Actions** link in left pane.

Click on **New Action** on the page and provide required details there.